# How to make a few collections of the same type in Isar db? [Flutter] [Isar]

Tags: flutter, dart, localdb, flutter-isar

Is there an option to make more than one collection with objects of the same type in Isar?

Isar doc: https://isar.dev/

how i create single Collection:

```
import 'package:isar/isar.dart';

@Collection()
class ProgramModel {
  @Id()
  int? id;
  String? title;
}
```

I want to have second collection of ProgramModel, but i can't add another @Collection() to same model.

Comment: A collection can only contain a single type of Dart object. Even in relational databases, you can't have two tables of the same name and properties. When a class is annotated with @Collection, it's equivalent to a table created in relational databases. If you try to annotate a similar class as a collection, the Isar code generator will detect it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Tried and can use same collection class in multiple isar instances (dbs).

To start new isar instance:

```html
Isar isarOne = await Isar.open(
  name: 'dbOne',
  schemas: [ContacSchema],
);


Isar isarTwo = await Isar.open(
  name: 'dbTwo',
  schemas: [ContacSchema],
);
```

In web, it creates 2 DBs inside IndexedDB.
On native also it will create 2 isar instances.

Wanted a way to use same collection class to create Multiple Collections in single isar instance, but seems that cannot be done.. so will proceed with multiple isar instances to have multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

either you could make a collection with other name of same object model, or else create this model out of the scope of the present isar(with a new isar db)

Comment: How to make a collection od same model, but with other name?

Comment: You can do that by changing class name

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new file and implement the ProgramModel @collection there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).